# React - Load JSON and render component

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, reactjs, ecmascript-6

As the title says, I'm trying to render a React component which contains data that I grabbed from a JSON by loading it using fetch().

The api call works just fine, but I'm not able to render the data.

Here's the code:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            user: {}
        }
    }

    getUserById(uId) {
        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${uId}`)
            .then( (response) => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then( (json) => {
                return json;
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            user: this.getUserById(4)
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>User</h1>
                <p>ID: {this.state.user.id}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById("container")
);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Any idea on solving this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue is in this line:

```
<div class="container"></div>
```

You defined `class` and getting it by `getElementById`.

Another change is, ajax call will be async so `getUserById` will not return the data immediately and `setState` will set `undefined` value in state variable not the data returned from server. To solve this problem do the `setState` once you get the response.

Check this:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            user: {}
        }
    }

    getUserById(uId){
        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${uId}`)
        .then( (response) => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then( (json) => {
            this.setState({
                user: json
            })
        });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getUserById(4);
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.user);
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>User</h1>
                <p>ID: hello</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById("container")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Note**: You are making a `ajax` call so instead of calling funtion inside setState, do the setState once you get the response, inside .then, like this:

```
.then(json => {
    this.setState({user: json});
 });
```

Comment: Hehe, yeah. I screwed it up in the snippet.
The note solved my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try binding the getUserById method and also setState for your user object with the json response.

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        user: {}
    }
this.getUserById = this.getUserById.bind(this); //add this to your constructor
}

getUserById(uId) {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${uId}`)
        .then( (response) => {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then( (json) => {
            return json; //setState in here with your ajax request**strong text**
        });
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        user: this.getUserById(4)
    })
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>User</h1>
            <p>ID: {this.state.user.id}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(
<App/>,
document.getElementById("container")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your mainly problem is that getUserById method does not return anything, you should be setting the state inside it instead. Then you have a problem with the id given to the main container, but I supose You made a mistake only in the snippet.

I've tested the code above, Try it:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            user: null
        }
    }

    getUserById(uId) {
        fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${uId}`)
            .then( (response) => {
                return response.json()
            })
            .then( (json) => {
                return json;
            })
            .then((result) => {
              this.setState({user: result});
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getUserById(4)
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.user);
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>User</h1>
                <p>{this.state.user != null ? this.state.user.id : 0}</p>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App/>,
    document.getElementById("container")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem what I can see - your fetch promise won't return data obtained from server, so my proposition is to setState inside your promise callback, so it should looks like:

```
getUserById(uId) {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${uId}`)
        .then(result => result.json())
        .then(json => {
            this.setState({user: json});
        });
}
componentDidMount() {
    this.getUserById(4);
}
```